# Why won't Codility execute my code when Eclipse will?

Tags: java, eclipse, collections

Working on the [BinaryGap](https://codility.com/programmers/lessons/18/) problem in preparation for a technical assessment. For whatever reason, my code compiles and runs just fine in Eclipse but not when run through Codility. Both "IDEs" supposedly execute in a Java8 environment. Here's the error:

```
 Example test:   1041
 WRONG ANSWER (got 0 expected 5)

  Example test:   15
  OK
```

```java
import java.util.TreeSet;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Gapper {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Solution sol = new Solution(1041);
        sol.solution(sol.getId());
    }
}

class Solution{
    private int count = 0;
    private int id;
    private String binary;
    private static final String Regex = "(1{1})([0]{1,})(1{1})";
    private Pattern pattern;
    private Matcher mat;
    private TreeSet<Integer> tree;
    public void setId(int id){
        this.id = id;
    }
    public int getId(){
        return this.id;
    }
    public int solution(int N){
        tree = new TreeSet<Integer>();
        this.binary = Integer.toBinaryString(id);
        for(int i = 0; i < this.binary.length(); i++){ 
            this.pattern= Pattern.compile(Regex);
            this.mat = this.pattern.matcher(this.binary.substring(i));
            while(this.mat.find()){
                if(this.mat.group().length() != 0){
                    tree.add(Integer.parseInt(this.mat.group().toString()));
                }
            }
        }

        int counter = 0;
        if(!tree.isEmpty()){
            String biggest = tree.last().toString();
            for(int i = 0; i < (biggest.length()); i++){
                if(biggest.charAt(i) == '0')counter++;
            }
            this.count = counter;
            System.out.println("Binary gap = "+count);
            return this.count;
        }else{
            return this.count;
        }
    }
    public Solution(int id){
        this.setId(id);
    }
    public Solution(){}
}
```

Comment: What is this" synchronizedNavigableSet"  method or  is a typo

Comment: Yes, typo from an earlier version of this code. Note edits.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This isn't a compilation error - codality successfully compiles and runs your code, it just alerts you that the code produces the wrong answer. In this case, for the input of 1041 the correct answer is 5, but your code gives 0.

I think that tackling this problem with a regex is the wrong approach. It forces you to make assumptions on how a number looks. [Bit shifting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html) and counting zeros may prove to be much simpler:

```
public int soltuion(int n) {
    int curr = 0;
    int max = 0;

    while (n > 0) {
        int bit = n & 1;
        n >>= 1;
        if (bit == 1) {
            if (curr > max) {
                max = curr;
            }
            curr = 0;
        } else {
            curr++;
        }
    }

    return max;
}
```

Comment: This code is not working with 2**n numbers like 32 (binary 100000). Its returning 5 for 32 whereas 0 is expected.

Comment: @Tarun why would you expect a `0`? There's a sequence of five zeros there.

Comment: As per Binary Gap definition sequence of consecutive zeros should be surrounded by ones at both ends. Therefore for 100000 (32) binary gap is 0 and for the  1000001 the Binary gap would be 5.

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct solution which works in all cases.

```
public int solution(int N) {

        int curr = 0;
        int max = 0;
        int state = 0;

        while (N > 0) {
            int bit = N & 1;
            switch (state) {
                case 0:
                    if (bit == 1 )
                    state = 1;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    curr = 0;
                    if (bit == 0) {
                        curr++;
                        state = 2;
                    }
                    break;
                case 2:
                    if (bit == 0) {
                        curr++;
                    }
                    else {
                        state = 1;
                        if (curr > max) {
                            max = curr;
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                }
            N >>= 1;
        }
        return max;
    }
```